# how to use react-addons-perf correctly?

Tags: reactjs

I import it in the index.js like below.

```
import Perf from 'react-addons-perf'; // ES6
window.Perf = Perf;
```

But when I run it in the console like below, it shows me the 'undefined'.
[image]

I just want to try it and learn it, but the offical doc seems not to tell it in detail. Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

There are a bunch of possible explanations here.

1. There is no indication in [the docs](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/perf.html) that `Perf.start()` returns anything - it's just a signal to the package that it should *start* recording performance data. You need to then call `Perf.stop()` to stop recording and `Perf.getLastMeasurements()` to report the results.
2. You also need to be using the minified production build of React. The normal development build does not include the code required for performance measurement.

There are a couple of articles linked in the documentation that go into more detail on how to use the library. Have a look at those & your problems will probably be solved.